# Is there a downside to using too many threads with pytest-xdist?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, pytest, context-switch, pytest-xdist

I'm running pytest on a server with 64 cores, and I'm currently using 16 threads with pytest. I could probably use a lot more without need for the cores to context switch, but I'm wondering if there's a downside to using more threads?